# The Positive Harmonic Current $T$ on the Homogeneous Manifold $M$ is a limit of a sequence of Smooth ones $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $M$?

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds, differential-forms, distribution-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathbb{M}$ be a **Homogeneous** (i.e, the automorphism group acts transitively) Complex Manifold of complex dimension $m$ and $T$ a (not necessarily Smooth) Positive Harmonic Current on $\mathbb{M}$.

It can be proved then that $T$ is a limit of a sequence of **Smooth** Positive Harmonic Currents $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$on $\mathbb{M}$.

Where can such proof be found?

Comment: Have you checked DeRham? The standard source, albeit not new, for currents.

Comment: @TedShifrin what are you talking about?

Comment: [This classic text](https://www.amazon.com/Differentiable-Manifolds-Grundlehren-mathematischen-Wissenschaften/dp/3642617549).

Comment: @TedShifrin which page?